# Twitch Bot Form wont Initialize

Tags: c#, visual-studio, initialization, windows-forms-designer, irc

I'm trying to make a chat bot for twitch and i want to make it in a Form so its very user friendly, i got the twitch communication done but now my form wont initialize. Please help.

```css
namespace TwitchBotForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IrcClient irc = new IrcClient("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "z_bot909", "oauth:dn2tixd1xd7krggyn49ztw08hmfjea");
            irc.joingRoom("z_dog909");
            irc.sendChatMessage("Startup Complete");
            while (true)
            {
                string message = irc.readMessage();
                string[] splitMessage = message.Split('#');
                if (message.Contains("!info"))
                {
                    irc.sendChatMessage("Please Keep all commands LowerCase I made this bot Myself and i think its pretty cool. do !Help for Commands");
                }
                if (message.Contains("!me"))
                {
                    irc.sendChatMessage(splitMessage[1].Split(':')[0]); //Username
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not put this infinite loop in constructor of your form.

Check [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waw3xexc(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to run background thread with windows forms.